# Keep audio-port active when screen turns off

Tags: audio, display

I've got a Samsung UE590 4k UHD Monitor, with audio output. I use this screen for my Windows PC and my Ubuntu laptop, so it's nice that I can get the audio via the monitor, so I don't have to switch more cables.

But whenever the screen turns off (into standy/sleep mode), the audio shuts down as well. An obvious solution would be to just configure my PC and laptop to 'never sleep', but I hate the idea of having the monitor burning uselessly whenever I just run Spotify whenever I have visitors or something.

So I was wondering, is it possible to configure the monitor/machines in such a way that whenever the display goes to sleep, the audio keeps going?

Mind you: This is not some issue with drivers or such, it isn't the monitor that shuts itself down after some time, this is purely when the computer would turn the display off (the audio keeps going, but the output goes out). If I would use the audio output on the laptop/pc instead of the screen, the audio does keep going after the screen goes dark.

Comment: Does the screen saver not solve this?

Comment: No ! When no signal is coming from display adapter, the monitor enters power saving mode and turns of all functions.